# Storing Image paths in XML and then returning image with query results

Tags: wpf, xml, image

I'm very new to development and SO, i'm trying to build a small program to allow users to search for a employee name and return other info including a staff photo.

Building it in WPF, with C# code behind and the staff details stored in an XML file.

I can get the staff details back from the XML by searching but i need to get the image returned too so it can be displayed in the datatemplate as the results.

How is best to store the info in the XML and retrieve it along with the search results?

Thanks in advance.

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     <Window.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="SearchResultsTemplate">
                <Grid Margin="4,0,4,8" Width="446" Height="68">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="8" Padding="2" Background="White">
                        <Image Width="40" Height="40" Source="{Binding Path=Avatar, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </Border>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,4,0,0">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="AuthorName" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Author, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        <Grid Margin="0,6,0,0">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="2" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="Message" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
             </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Window.Resources>
        <ScrollViewer  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" BorderThickness="1">
 <ItemsControl x:Name="SearchResults" Margin="0,8,0,0" 
  Grid.Row="1" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SearchResultsTemplate}" />
             </ScrollViewer>
```

Code behind:

```
 XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("data.xml");
 SearchResults.ItemsSource = from item in xdoc.Descendants("Item")
                             where (string)item.Element("Author") == searchInput
                             select new
                             {
                                Author = (string)item.Element("Author"),
                                Message = (string)item.Element("Message"),
                                Avatar = (string)item.Element("Avatar")
                            };
```

Comment: Hey, that looks great. I will try that out and see if it gives me what i was looking for.

Comment: This code example helped me get it to do what i was looking for. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would say you should store the path (URI) of the pictures in your XML and retrieve this path with the rest of the details data. Then in the DataTemplate you could set the Images Source property with a Binding to your path then it should work. If not then use a converter which returns a BitMapImage from your path.

[Image Source Binding with a Converter](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/wpf/thread/f94cc770-8d86-4a9f-a5f9-2ee2ea146c1a)

If you are new to WPF and developing then you should read some books about WPF and MVVM too it is interesting and a good way to start. ;)

Comment: If you bind the Source property of an Image control to a property of type string of your data object that returns the path to the image file (say Person.ImagePath), you wouldn't need a converter. Value conversion is done automatically.

Comment: I wasn't sure if that works too, so i wrote he could do it with a converter. :)

Comment: Thanks both, I'm going to give all the suggestions a try, so I can learn different ways of doing this. Will definitely be getting myself some more books and resources about WPF etc.

Comment: @markhlong I'm glad i could help, there are some great books from Wrox and Apress and MS too.

Comment: I used this advice along with the other post's code example to make the function work. Thanks for your help, setting the Images Source with a Binding was what i was looking for I think.

Comment: You are welcome, if my answer helped too then you could upwote it too. :D:D